# crypt() function not giving proper hashes

Tags: php, password-hash

I have made an password hashing script using **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281373/hash-vs-crypt-function-comparison)**, i am getting it to work correctly except some times the crypt function is giving hash as "*0", and then it fails.

**PHP Codes**

```
    $password='password';
    $salt = '$2y$07$';
    $salt .= base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM));
    $salt .='$$';
    $password_hash = crypt($password, $salt)';

    echo $password_hash.'<br />';
```

**Using above i am getting values as**

```
    $salt = '$2y$07$8K3i8rJ7n7bsJA36CfbabQ==$$';
    $crypt_password = $password_hash;
    $crypt_password = '$2y$07$8K3i8rJ7n7bsJA36CfbabO9ojj2hl61azl8CubJQhRTgla4ICiCVC';
    if (crypt($password,$crypt_password)===$crypt_password)
    {
    echo 'password verified';
    }
    else{
    echo 'password NOT verified';
    }
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to make it work correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: `$crypt_password = $password_hash` sorry i didn't mention above

Comment: The verification step is correct (`crypt` extracts the salt out of the "hash" returned by `crypt`). The problem is, that `base64_encode` emits invalid characters for example `+` (accepted characters by `crypt`: `"./0-9A-Za-z"`). If `base64_encode` returns an invalid character `"*0"` is returned.

Comment: Why are you writing your own when there's several [bcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) implementations here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `base64_encode` may generate a string with '+' symbol, which is considered an incorrect salt by `crypt` function.

`var_dump` your `$salt` along with `$password`, and you'll see that each time `+` character is used in the salt, crypt function will return a `'*0'` string - the sign of failure.

One possible way of solving it is replacing all '+' signs with '.':

```
$salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);
```